# Maximum 10000 parameters allowed in inbound request

Tags: websphere-7

I am getting the below error whenever the size of parameters in my form exceeds 10,000.

> com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.util.RequestUtils parseQueryString
>   SRVE0325E: Exceeding maximum parameters allowed per request 10,000

I did some investigation and found that the issue can be resolved by adding a parameter `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest` in webcontainer custom properties and setting its value to -1.

However my problem is that I am getting this error only in production environment and not in test environment. The parameter `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest` is not set in test environments also.. The version of websphere application server in test environment is `7.0.0.19` and that in production is `7.0.0.23`.

There is a WEB server infront of my WAS server and i also checked the value of `PoolDataSize` parameter in `plugin.xml` and found its value to be "-1".

Does different fixpack versions of websphere in test and production have to do anything with this?
Please help

Comment: I had the same error and it was a big issue here.  
Setting the value to -1 did the trick.  
Though you have included that in your question, can you please write it down as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

The `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest` property to change the maximum number of parameters allowed in your inbound requests did not exist *until* WebSphere 7.0.0.23.

The property was introduced in order to address a [potential DOS vulnerability](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592923).

[It's hard to figure why your application needs more than 10000 parameters, though.]

Comment: But the default value for the inbound requests is 10,000 for Websphere versions earlier than 7.0.0.23. So i should get the same error when number of parameters exceeds 10,000 in test environment also. But i am not getting the error in test environment.

Comment: Do you mean that you're able to specify `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.maxParamPerRequest` in 7.0.0.19?  FWIW, the property was added later, so even if you manage to modify the configuration files 7.0.0.19 to specify it, it'll be ignored.